# How can I boot alpine-linux from CF card (in Soekris net4801)?

Tags: boot, embedded, vfat, alpine-linux

I've installed according to https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Create_a_Bootable_Compact_Flash#Automated and successfully activated serial console as outlined in https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Enable_Serial_Console_on_Boot#Example_syslinux.cfg .

Now when I boot, I get this error:

```
[    0.000000] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): A valid RSDP was not found (20160831/tbxfroot-244)
[    1.826586] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): A valid RSDP was not found (20160831/tbxfroot-244)
[    2.292134] dmi: Firmware registration failed.
[   11.617601] i8042: Can't read CTR while initializing i8042
[   11.648009] microcode: no support for this CPU vendor
Mounting boot media failed.
initramfs emergency recovery shell launched. Type 'exit' to continue boot
sh: can't access tty; job control turned off
/ #
```

I am dropped to a shell, /sysroot is empty and I cannot find any of the disks:

```
/ # modprobe vfat && cd /dev && ls  | grep -vE 'ram|tty|loop'
bus
console
cpu_dma_latency
full
grsec
kmsg
mem
memory_bandwidth
network_latency
network_throughput
null
ptmx
pts
random
rd
rtc0
shm
urandom
vcs
vcs1
vcsa
vcsa1
vga_arbiter
zero
```

These are the current mounts:

```
/ # mount
rootfs on / type rootfs (rw,size=56804k,nr_inodes=14201)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=2048k,nr_inodes=14203,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
shm on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
```

This is the system, as shown by the BIOS while booting:

```
comBIOS ver. 1.33  20080103  Copyright (C) 2000-2007 Soekris Engineering.

net4801

0128 Mbyte Memory                        CPU Geode SC1100 233 Mhz

Pri Mas  SanDisk SDCFX3-4096             LBA Xlt 995-128-63  4013 Mbyte
Pri Sla  HTS726060M9AT00                 LBA Xlt 1024-255-63  58605 Mbyte
```

**How can I get these drives (or at least the CF) to be visible/mountable and boot correctly from them?**

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste your syslinux.cfg  ?
Which version of Alpine are you using ?
How is the CF card recognized by the system ?
Thanks.

.: Francesco